# Are FutureCallbacks added to the ListenableFuture executed asynchronously?

Tags: java, asynchronous, guava

In the code below, I added 2 FutureCallbacks to a single ListenableFuture.

And my question is: will the 2 FutureCallbacks be executed by the order I add them, or will they run separately and asynchronously?

The JavaDoc said, **Registers separate success and failure callbacks to be run when the Future's computation is complete or, if the computation is already complete, immediately.
There is no guaranteed ordering of execution of callbacks, but any callback added through this method is guaranteed to be called once the computation is complete.**

I tried to add `Thread.sleep(1000)` to one of the FutureCallbacks, then I found it blocks the other one, which confused me.

And I've also tried the addListener method, it runs asynchronously, that's for sure.

```
ListeningExecutorService service = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10));
final ListenableFuture<String> future = service.submit(new Callable<String>() {
  @Override
  public String call() throws Exception {
    return "hello";
  }
});

Futures.addCallback(future, new FutureCallback<String>() {
  @Override
  public void onSuccess(String result) {
    System.out.println(result+ " world");
  }

  @Override
  public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
  }
});

Futures.addCallback(future, new FutureCallback<String>() {
  @Override
  public void onSuccess(String result) {
    System.out.println(result+ " me");
  }

  @Override
  public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you point or quote to where it says they should be async?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, sorry, I made a mistake, I didn't saw it in the wiki, it's in the javadoc.

Comment: You can quote/link that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will the 2 `FutureCallback`s be executed by the order I add them, or will
>   they run separately and asynchronously

First, it's important to note that `Callback` instances and listeners registered after a `Future` has completed trigger immediately.

The [javadoc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#addCallback%28com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture,%20com.google.common.util.concurrent.FutureCallback%29) states

> Note: If the callback is slow or heavyweight, consider supplying an
>   executor. If you do not supply an executor, `addCallback` will use a
>   direct executor, which carries some caveats for heavier operations.
>   For example, the callback may run on an unpredictable or undesirable
>   thread:
>
> - If the input Future is done at the time `addCallback` is called, **`addCallback` will execute the callback inline**.
> - If the input Future is not yet done, `addCallback` will schedule the callback to be run by the thread that completes the input Future,
>     which may be an internal system thread such as an RPC network thread.
>
> **Also note that, regardless of which thread executes the callback, all
>   other registered but unexecuted listeners are prevented from running
>   during its execution, even if those listeners are to run in other
>   executors.**

You can control if they are run separately by providing separate `Executor`s when adding them (or the same but pooled). If you don't, the behavior is unpredictable, as the javadoc states.

(This is from a more recent version of Guava, but I think it applies to older versions as well.)

Comment: Thanks, so it does block the others. That sucks, I'm gonna have to use the addListener

Comment: @fish748 If the `result` is mutable, you have to be careful with parallel execution.

Comment: @fish748: You don't have to use `addListener`, you can just use the other overload of `addCallback` that takes an `Executor`...

Comment: @fish748: And what happened?

Comment: @LouisWasserman you were right, I didn't read the doc carefully enough, my bad.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis already done, but I wouldn't be able to check the doc more carefully without you, so thank you anyway

Comment: @fish748 I've updated my answer. Callbacks can be run in parallel. They will, however, block any unexecuted listeners.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thanks. BTW, if I want a ListeningExecutorService to run infinitely and trigger my callbacks everytime it has a result, how can I do that?

Comment: @fish748 The callbacks are registered on futures, not on the `ListeningExecutorService`. You could write your own `ListeningExecutorService` which wraps the Guava one and registers your callbacks on all `Future`s.